# Connecting Deno Backend to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, deno

I am new to Deno. I was following a tutorial and I was learning about how to connect my Deno backend to MongoDB. If I am honest the Tutorial I am watching right is a little bit old and so many things changed since the video came out. Can someone help how I can connect to my MongoDB database?
Thank you

I tried to use [dataAPI](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/rust/getting-started-deno-mongodb/) based on this struction but when I tried it with postmen the response I got was the URL is not found. And that was weird for me apparently the article is new. I tried to use MongoClient. But again I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to the Deno Discord community I understand that you need to add a couple of things. The URL that mongo would generate for you is something like this:
`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`.But your URL should be something like this: `mongodb+srv://${user}:${pass}@${cluster}/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=admin`.Again I really want to thank the Deno community, They are really fun to work with.